# How to encrypt client-side with AWS KMS using the C# SDK

Tags: c#, encryption, amazon-web-services, key-management

Is there already a C# library for encrypting and decrypting data using Amazon's Key Management Service (KMS) but *without* sending your sensitive data to Amazon (i.e. using "envelope encryption" as described in their [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/workflow.html))? Something that handles the nitty gritty details of choosing algorithm, mode, IV, etc.?

To be clear, I'm not asking how to do it... just trying to find out if I've wasted my time rolling my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing this after a couple of years. In case anyone arrives here looking for a solution, the one I wrote is open-source, called [AwsContrib.EnvelopeCrypto](https://github.com/ica-carealign/AwsContrib.EnvelopeCrypto). I do not know if it is still in use anywhere.